# how to edit document root of subdomain in bluehost CPanel

Tags: cpanel, bluehost, cpanel-uapi

Hope someone could help, am new to bluehost and had a shared hosting subscription. Now my issue is how to modify the subdomain document root.

example: from `public_html/sub` to `public_html/sub/public`

also when i created a subdomain it doesn't even allow me to add "/" unlike in godaddy

thanks.

Comment: This is not about programming. -1

Comment: well its true, the thing is I couldn't find any other options other than the answer i posted

Comment: The answer may be correct and useful, but that doesn't change the fact that the question is off-topic here to begin with, as this is a programming forum and the question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, some how I landed to this URL
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/dm/subdomain
and it allowed to to add "/" with subdomain, hope it helps

[image]

Comment: So the old interface is better than the new one. Thanks I did not want to have to talk to chat again 

Comment: Good lord, this worked for me too.  What a find...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution so on the root folder add or edit if already existing .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/public/$1 [L]
```

Done

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this via the Bluehost interface, I followed these steps:

1. Go to 'My Domains' under 'Domains' in the left-hand column
2. Click the 'Manage' drop down and choose 'Unassign'
3. Click the green box that says 'Unassign'
4. Go to 'Assign' under 'Domains' in the left-hand column
5. Go to 'Subdomains' under 'Domains' in the left-hand column (If you don't click 'Assign first, then clicking 'Subdomains' takes you to a different page...)
6. Under the 'Existing Subdomains' header, find the subdomain with the Document Root you want to change and click the red trash can under 'Actions'
7. Now you can re-assign your domain as an addon or whatever and give it a new Document Root. (I should note, that none of these steps deleted my document root directory).
8. Go to 'Assign' under 'Domains' in the left-hand column
9. Follow the steps to assign an existing domain

Comment: I should mention that because I had to create a new account on Stack Overflow, I am a newbie again and can't post screenshots in my post, otherwise I would have done so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the document root in cPanel worked for me, so it might be worth a try.

1. Go into the settings for the site you want to change in the Websites area, then click Advanced at the top.
2. From there, click "Manage" under cPanel, then choose the "Domains" link (or just search for "Domains").
3. Click "Manage" to the right of the domain (or subdomain) you want to change, and there will be a spot to update the document root on that page.

Best of luck!